# How can I set Lighthouse CI to only test accessibility?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, gatsby, lighthouse

I'm setting lighthouse ci to run in a Github action but my app is made with Gatsby and is not intended to be a PWA and when I run `lhci autorun` it keeps asking me to include manifest and a bunch of things related to a PWA. The only aspect I want lighthouse to check is accessibility.

This is my actual github action:

```
lighthouseci:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
     - run: yarn && sudo yarn global add @lhci/cli@0.6.x
     - run: yarn build
     - run: lhci autorun
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just get it working, As Graham said on one reply we can disable any category we want.

```js
{
  "ci": {
    "assert": {
      "assertions": {
        "categories:performance": "off",
        "categories:pwa": "off",
        "categories:accessibility": ["error", { "minScore": 1 }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `--only-categories` as one of the flags you set.

Set the flag to only run accessibility as follows if using the command line:

`lighthouse https://example.com --only-categories=accessibility`

### Using Github Actions

I personally don't use Github actions but from what I understand [you will have to include a config file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/lighthouse-check#usage-overriding-config-and-option-defaults) in order to run specific tests.

```
{
  "config": {
    "settings": {
      "onlyCategories": ["accessibility"]
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit to include lighthouse-ci config

From what I can gather if you are using [lighthouse-ci](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci) then you need to add a config file "lighthouserc.js" to the working directory with the following format:

```
module.exports = {
  ci: {
    collect: {
      settings: {
         //set which categories you want to run here.
         onlyCategories: ['accessibility']
      }
    },
    assert: {
      // assert options here
    },
    upload: {
      // upload options here
    },
    server: {
      // server options here
    },
    wizard: {
      // wizard options here
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, but that's another module, the one that I'm using is https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci

Comment: Not familiar with it but from what I can see you might have to manually disable all the audits you don't want to run using https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#settings

Comment: Although after reading a bit more it appears to just take a standard config file so just implement that (which is very similar to what I posted) https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#more-examples - with an example at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/config/perf-config.js showing how to only run the performance category (so just change that to `onlyCategories: ['accessibility']` from `onlyCategories: ['performance']`)

Comment: edited my answer to include what i believe is the correct config format, but you will have to test that youself.